# How to enable power on by keyboard on a B550 AORUS PRO-P motherboard?

Tags: keyboard, bios, motherboard, uefi

I try to power on my PC using the keyboard.
My BIOS/UEFI Settings are missing the older "Wake On keyboard/Password" settings. I have disabled ERP and wake on LAN works flawlessly, but I cant power on by keypress.
Please note that the motherboard does not have any PS2 ports, the keyboard is connected on a USB2 port.

The BIOS version I use is AMI F16.

Is this possible?

Comment: I do not think you can. The power button is a soft button to the PSU, it is not a keyboard key.